# Next.js, getStaticProps not working with component but does with page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

If I visit this code on local host, it is able to pull data from the API and then display it on a card.

```
import { formatNumber, parseTimestampJM } from '../../utils';

import { Card } from './UserTransactions.styled';

// STEP 1 : fetch data from api
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales'
  );
  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}

function UserTransactionsComponent({ data }) {
  const results = data;
  console.log(results);
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div>
        <h1>This is a list of User Transactions!</h1>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {results.data.map((result) => {
          const {
            sale_id,
            buyer,
            seller,
            listing_price,
            listing_symbol,
            created_at_time,
          } = result;

          if (buyer !== null) {
            return (
              <Card>
                <li key={sale_id}>
                  <h3>
                    {seller} just sold item number {sale_id} to {buyer} for{' '}
                    {formatNumber(listing_price)} {listing_symbol} at{' '}
                    {parseTimestampJM(created_at_time)}
                  </h3>
                </li>
              </Card>
            );
          }
        })}
      </ul>
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default UserTransactionsComponent;
```

When I create a component and then call it in to my index page like so:

```
    <PageLayout>
      <Banner modalType={MODAL_TYPES.CLAIM} />
      <ExploreCard />
      <HomepageStatistics />
      <Title>New &amp; Noteworthy</Title>
      <UserTransactionsComponent />

      <Grid items={featuredTemplates} />
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

export default MarketPlace;
```

it gives me the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

```
  27 | <ul>
> 28 |   {results.data.map((result) => {
     |           ^
  29 |     const {
  30 |       sale_id,
  31 |       buyer,
```

I think that the reason I'm getting this error is because of the way the data is being fetched. Perhaps it's not being included in the component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods like `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` work only for page components inside the `pages` folder. More specifically, they only work inside [files that define routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts).

Here is what the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#where-can-i-use-getstaticprops) says about `getStaticProps` for example:

> `getStaticProps` can only be exported from a **page**. You **cannot** export it from non-page files, `_app`, `_document`, or `_error`.

If you wanna use `UserTransactionsComponent` as a normal component, you should use `useEffect` and make the API call on mount:

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"

function UserTransactionsComponent() {

  const [data, setData]=useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicmarket/v1/sales'
      );
      const {data} = await res.json();
      setData(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  },[]);

  if(!data){
   return (<div>Loading...</div>)
  }

  return (
    <PageLayout>
      <div>
        <h1>This is a list of User Transactions!</h1>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {data.map((result) => {
          const {
            sale_id,
            buyer,
            seller,
            listing_price,
            listing_symbol,
            created_at_time,
          } = result;

          if (buyer !== null) {
            return (
              <Card>
                <li key={sale_id}>
                  <h3>
                    {seller} just sold item number {sale_id} to {buyer} for{' '}
                    {formatNumber(listing_price)} {listing_symbol} at{' '}
                    {parseTimestampJM(created_at_time)}
                  </h3>
                </li>
              </Card>
            );
          }
        })}
      </ul>
    </PageLayout>
  );
}

export default UserTransactionsComponent;
```