# getServerSideProps function wont send data to main component

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-typescript, next.js13

I'm using typescript and getServerSideProps in my own project but it seems getServerSideProps wont send data to main component. Here are all code I used:

```
import Modal from "@/components/modal";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Check from "../components/check";
import { setArayeshgahInfo } from "../redux/slice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useAppSelector, updatesetArayeshgahStatus } from "../redux/slice";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export interface IArayeshgah {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  check?: boolean | undefined;
}

function SelectArayeshgah(props: IArayeshgah[]) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(props);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //if (props.data) console.log("props ", props.data);
    //dispatch(setArayeshgahInfo(props));
  }, []);

  const arayeshgahInfos = useAppSelector((state) => state);

  const toggle_Arayeshgah_State = ({ id }: { id: string }) => {
    dispatch(updatesetArayeshgahStatus({ id }));
  };

  const ArayeshgahItems = () => {
    return (
      <div className="flex mt-4">
        {arayeshgahInfos?.map((item) => (
          <div
            className="w-52 rounded-xl shadow-sm bg-gray-300 border text-sm h-10 flex justify-between pr-2 pl-2 items-center"
            onClick={() => toggle_Arayeshgah_State({ id: item.id })}
          >
            <span>{item.title}</span>
            <Check isCheck={item.check!} size="sm" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      callback={() => {}}
      denyText="انصراف"
      headerText="انتخاب آرایشگاه"
      acceptText="تایید"
      bodyText="پس از انتخاب آرایشگاه مورد نظر بر روی دکمه تایید بزنید"
    >
      <ArayeshgahItems />
    </Modal>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return { props: [{ id: "DKLGJDFKLHJDFLK", title: "تک چهره", check: false }] };
};

export default SelectArayeshgah;
```

How can I fix a problem ?

try to send data from getServerSideProps function to SelectArayeshgah function

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using getServerSideProps if you're not fetching any server side data, is that necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js, getStaticProps not working with component but does with page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310271/next-js-getstaticprops-not-working-with-component-but-does-with-page)

Comment: this is my answer:works only for page components inside pages folder. tnx to Youssouf Oumar . but I want to prevent access my component by url